# Setting the text of a programatically created button

Tags: android, user-interface

Basic question regarding setting the text of a programatically created button. As seen in my code below I've done the basics in terms of creating the button but my button appears as seen in my attached image. Basically the text in the button doesn't appear as expected. Any ideas why?

Note: I've declared button as a public instance variable right above my onCreate() and has been added correctly to my relative layout using addView();

```
// Create User button
btnUserAdmin = new Button(this);

// Customise the UserAdmin button
btnUserAdmin.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
btnUserAdmin.setTextSize(13.7f);
btnUserAdmin.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));
btnUserAdmin.setText("USER ADMINISTRATION");
btnUserAdmin.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Try using a smaller text size (try 12.0). Also a smaller padding would help (try setting 4 as padding, just to experiment)

Comment: Show the code you use to add the button to a viewgroup.  It looks like the layout parameters you use either don't allow the button to wrap its content or the viewgroup you're adding it to isn't big enough.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo: Ur suggestion worked i.e. adding the paddings .. cheers man

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the dimensions of the button, otherwise the size could be unexpected. For instance

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(              
                                          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   
                                          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT   );

btnUserAdmin.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

also, you can directly set them when you add the buttom

```
yourRelativeLatout.addView(btnUserAdmin, lp);
```

Also remember that numeric values for the dimensions (of the bottom or the layout) usually are evil. As you can, use only  `WRAP_CONTENT` and `MATCH_PARENT`